# Pokemon Go does not level up

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I went up to level 14 yesterday, but I never got the whole animation thingy, and therefore never got my bonus items. I am at 5000 XP of 15k to level 15, and still nothing. How can I get the items assosiated with the level up? Or force it to show up?

I tried;

- Restarting the app
- Relogging
- Restarted my phone
- Cleared cache
- Reinstalled

But it still does not recognize that I leveled up. Any ideas?

I have searched a lot about it, but I only get like 'how to level up fast' and 'fastest ways to level up' articles on different pages.

Comment: May be there were server issues. You might have received the items for levelling up.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when there are server issues/connection issues when the events are triggered.

But you receive these items usually. This happens during egg incubation too. Check your items section for the following.

---

**Level 14**

Rewards :

- Great Ball x10
- Super Potion x10
- Revive x3
- Razz Berry x3

**[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items)**

Comment: Never got it. Thats why I askef in the first place

Comment: Oh. then  I'm not sure. May be you should report this issue to Niantic through the app.

Comment: I just went up to 15, level 14 reward was still not recieved

Comment: I guess I'm never getting it. Im on level 19 so I guess I have to realize it is gone